# JAX WSclient casting a stub to a bindingprovider

Tags: binding, jax-ws, stub

Whenwriting a JAXWS client, thisis what I have used in the past:

```
// CALL SERVICE
EPaymentsService bPayService = new EPaymentsService();
ServiceInterface stub = bPayService.getPort();
BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) stub;
Map<String, Object> rc = bp.getRequestContext();
String endPointUrl = propFile.getString(Constants.END_POINT_URL);
rc.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endPointUrl);
// RESPONSE
ResponseMessage resMessage = stub.sendMessage(reqMessage);
```

In my code, ServiceInterface does not extend BindingProvider.So how come we dont get an error while casting

```
BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) stub;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) stub;
```

This is a narrowing reference conversion. According to one of the rules of Narrowing reference conversion, an interface type `K` can be assigned to a non-parameterized interface type `J`, provided `K` is not a sub-type of `J`(you wouldn't require an explicit cast if `K` were a sub-type of `J`).

```
J j = (J) K;
```

If the cast fails, a ClassCastException is thrown at runtime.

```
InputStream in = System.in;
Runnable r = (Runnable) in;
```

The above snippet compiles because both `InputStream` and `Runnable` are non-parameterized interfaces, but would result in a `ClassCastException` at run-time.

A cast from `ServiceInterface` to `BindingProvider` works because `getPort` returns a dynamic proxy class that implements the `WSBindingProvider` interface, which in turn extends the `BindingProvider` interface.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it is like converting an Integer to a Float? Or is it the reverse?

Comment: No, bro. It's not like that. You cannot cast an `Integer` to `Float` or vice-versa because they are both class types. But you can assign a `Float` or `Integer` to `Number` without any cast since they extend `Number`.

Comment: The specification of this (i.e. that the Proxy, which is returned by the method javax.xml.ws.Service#getPort, MUST implement interface javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider) is found in section 4.2.3 of the JAX-WS specification, currently downloadable from http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=224.